# Error: "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges

Tags: bash, docker, nginx, permissions, dockerfile

Hi I am getting the following errors as I try to implement a new user in my dockerfile rather than using the root user.

```
2020-10-16T09:28:04.554363522Z nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2020-10-16T09:28:04.564383012Z nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020-10-16T09:28:06.882365055Z nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2020-10-16T09:28:06.891084727Z nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020-10-16T09:28:09.331807870Z nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2020-10-16T09:28:09.342560643Z nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Below is the following dockerfile that I have created. I have created a new called api-gateway, however, when I build my docker image and run the container I get the above errors.

Any suggestions to what changes I need to implement to get the user working instead of root user?

```
USER root
RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y nginx procps shadow-utils net-tools ca-certificates dirmngr gnupg wget vim\
            && microdnf clean all \
            && rpm -q procps-ng

ENV NGINX_USER="api-gatway" \
    NGINXR_UID="8987" \
    NGINX_GROUP="api-gatway" \
    NGINX_GID="8987"     

RUN set -ex; \
  groupadd -r --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_GROUP"; \
  useradd -r --uid "$NGINXR_UID" --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_USER" 

#To start up NGINX 
EXPOSE 80
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx/

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/tmp/

RUN chown api-gatway /var/lib/nginx/
RUN chownd api-gatway /var/log/nginx/
USER api-gatway
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Since you specify an alternate `USER` in the Dockerfile, nginx can't switch users at startup time.  You can specify a user in the Dockerfile, or the nginx configuration, but it doesn't make sense to do both.

Comment: hmm, i have run the docker-image on Kubernates cluster, the user error seems to go away. But the permission denied error still remains  nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: It appears the nginx is already running as a user api-gatway, hence the warning. How did you check that it is not the case? What is the output of `ps aux | grep nginx` ?

Answer (score 10):

Please add the volume and volume mount section in your deployment yaml file :

volumes:

```
- name: nginx-dir
  emptyDir: { }
- name: nginx-empty
  emptyDir: { }
- name: nginx-run
  emptyDir: { }
```

volumeMounts:

```
- mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
  name: nginx-dir
- mountPath: /var/cache/nginx/client_temp
  name: nginx-empty
- mountPath: /var/run/
  name: nginx-run
```

This should allow you to access the particular dir without root user.

Answer (score 9):

NGINX has now an official unprivileged Docker image, with more fine-grained changes (below are only "notable" ones, there is more of them):

- removing `user` directive in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
- moving PID from `/var/run/nginx.pid` to `/tmp/nginx.pid`
- changing `*_temp_path` variables to `/tmp/*`
- changing the listening port to a non-root one (80->8080).

To see all these changes, please check out the source at [nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged) or simply pull one of the resulting unprivileged Docker images from the Docker Hub ([nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged)), and I strongly recommend the one based on Alpine rather than on Debian to avoid frequent vulnerabilities:

```
docker pull nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:stable-alpine
```

Comment: This saved my day!! Thanks a ton for sharing and its a very useful piece of information if somebody is using `runAsNonRoot: true` in their deployment.